# googleapiclient returns Bad Request error when trying to send email through Gmail

Tags: google-api, gmail

I am getting the following error when my python code tries to send a simple test email.

`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json returned "Bad Request">`

My code looks like so:

```
      scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']
      path = <path to my serice account key in json format>
      self.credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
          path + <service account key>, scope )
      self.EMAIL_FROM = self.credentials.service_account_email
      self.delegated_credentials = self.credentials.create_delegated(self.EMAIL_FROM)
      self.service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=self.delegated_credentials)

   def send( self, to, subject, body ):
      message = MIMEText(body)
      message['to'] = to
      message['from'] = <valid email account>
      message['subject'] = subject
      message = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}

      try:
         message = (self.service.users().messages().send(userId=<valid email account>, body=message)
                    .execute())
         print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
         return message
      except errors.HttpError as error:
         print('An error occurred: %s' % error)
```

I followed the steps closely to https://medium.com/lyfepedia/sending-emails-with-gmail-api-and-python-49474e32c81f and existing Gmail API documentation. I think I have setup all the access and permissions correctly. What am I missing and why the error?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was with the self.EMAIL_FROM above. This needs to be set to a user with the right set of permissions to be able to send the email. That solves my problem to begin with. However, it is not clear to me what permissions I need to set for a user to be used for delegation. currently it only seems to work with administrator email.

If someone has some clarity on that, please respond.

Comment: With domain wide delegation, which was already set in my case, this works. I was using an alias email in my code and that doesnt work. If you use the original, it works.